iterate over IntFlag enumeration using iter differs in python 3.8 and 3.12.4
I have the following working in python 3.8.1
@unique
class Encoder(IntFlag):
    # H1 sensor signal
    H1 = 0x00
    # H2 sensor signal
    H2 = 0x01
    # H3 sensor signal
    H3 = 0x02

Then I am trying to catch with an assert if the value is not within the enum, i.e.
from enum import unique, IntFlag
signal = Encoder.H1
assert signal in iter(Encoder), f"Valid Encoder line is integer 0 to 2 inclusive."

I noticed on python 3.8, the signal in iter(Encoder) returns True but False in python 3.12.4

It might be a change in some version from 3.8.1 to 3.12.4 but I am not sure where to star looking for getting this working in both.

enum.Flag implements __contains__.
For membership checks, drop the iter call and just use:
signal in Encoder

This will work in both 3.8.1 and 3.12.4.
Note: The change in iteration behavior for flags happened in Python 3.11 and is mentioned in the changelog here.
Also, you should probably be using IntEnum rather than IntFlag anyway. IntFlag would be appropriate in a use case where Encoder.H2 | Encoder.H3 was meaningful, and meant "both of these". In your use case, Encoder.H2 | Encoder.H3 is an invalid value.

The change in iteration behaviour is not directly mentioned in the changelog. Rather that H1 is no longer considered a canonical form. Instead it is considered an alias for something like H2 & H3.

@Dunes It is a combination of that and Flag.__iter__ being added. The last and third-to-last bullet points in my link. Not sure how Ethan managed to change this without a deprecation period, it looks like a backwards-breaking change to me.

Related: https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/109633

I am wondering if there is a regression here. For instance, H0 is considered a member of the enum and continues to exist as an attribute on the enum. However, its name is no longer returned by dir(Encoder). This is contrary to the documentation for __dir__, which says it returns all members -- canonical and aliases alike.

Also worth noting that __contains__ also returns true for any composite flag value, not just named flags. eg. assert (H2 | H3) in Encoder, but assert (H2 | H3) not in Encoder.__members__
